# can not run CommandButton1_Click in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am almost a newbie for Excel VBA. 
I am trying to display values of some cells from a worksheet on the UserForm2 and unload the form when user clicks the CommandButton1.
To avoid building a class for my controls, I am starting with a draft UserForm where all the components I will need are placed on it.
I set the positions of the text boxes, fill them in, set the position of the CommandButton1. These are all Ok, all shows up as expected/planned.
when I click the CommandButton1 on form I hear a "Ding" and the "clicked CB1" message - which I expect to see - is not displayed.
What is that I am doing wrong or what is missing?

```
Option Explicit
Public leftOfForm As Long
Public topOfForm As Long
Public widthOfForm As Long
Public heightOfForm As Long
' ***********************************
Dim numInfoMessages  As Long
Dim heightBox As Long
Dim lengthTextbox As Long
Dim lengthCommandButton As Long
Dim numberOfScreenRows As Long
Dim horizantalPadding As Long
Dim verticalPadding As Long
Dim indexLoop As Integer
Dim contr As Control
Dim theFontSize As Integer

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'
'   Just to confirm it is ok --- current userform will be unloaded
'
    MsgBox "clicked CB1"
End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_initialize()
'
'   Save forms current info - not needed in fact
'
    theFontSize = 12
    leftOfForm = UserForm2.Left
    topOfForm = UserForm2.top
    widthOfForm = UserForm2.Width
    heightOfForm = UserForm2.Height
    numInfoMessages = 6
'
'  Calculate userform size based on number of lines to be displayed
'
    heightBox = 25
    lengthTextbox = 500
    lengthCommandButton = 90
    verticalPadding = 20
    horizantalPadding = 15
    numberOfScreenRows = (numInfoMessages + 1) * 2 + 1
'
'   Resize form according to the results
'
    UserForm2.Width = horizantalPadding * 3 + lengthTextbox + 10
    UserForm2.Height = verticalPadding * (numberOfScreenRows + 2)
    UserForm2.top = 0
    UserForm2.Left = 0             
'
'   Fill in and allocate the text boxes
'
    indexLoop = 1
    For Each contr In UserForm2.Controls
        If TypeName(contr) = "TextBox" Then
            contr.top = (indexLoop) * 2 * verticalPadding
            contr.Left = horizantalPadding
            contr.Width = lengthTextbox
            contr.Height = heightBox
            contr.BorderStyle = 1
            contr.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.messagesPageName).Range("B" & indexLoop + 1).Value
            contr.WordWrap = False
            contr.MultiLine = False
            contr.Font.Size = theFontSize
            indexLoop = 1 + indexLoop
        End If
    Next
'
'   Allocate the command button
'
    For Each contr In UserForm2.Controls
        If TypeName(contr) = "CommandButton" Then
            contr.top = (indexLoop) * 2 * verticalPadding
            contr.Width = lengthCommandButton
            contr.Height = heightBox
            contr.Width = lengthCommandButton
            contr.Left = UserForm2.Width / 2 - contr.Width / 2
            contr.top = (indexLoop) * 2 * verticalPadding
            contr.Font.Size = theFontSize
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mustafa, I generally use Userform_Activate(), that execute the code everytime Userform.Show is called, better than Userform_Load... to close the form, I use Me.Hide, try to check if you don’t renamed the form CommandButton_1 my clue is because generally is Private Sub when you click in a button

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed the name of CommandButton1?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I did not change the name. I only changed the caption.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for the hint/recomendation.

Comment: Hi, someone from my office offered to build a new form (UserForm3) then create all controls and empty subs there and copy my existing code into those subs. This was funny but I gave it a chance. There is no logical explanation for this but UserForm3 is doing exactly as expected.      Rodrigo Moraes thanks for your recommendation I will also try it.